# has_one :through => :belongs_to produces bad query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Existing associations

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :location
  has_one :geofence, :through => :location
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :locations
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :geofence
end

class Geofence < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end
```

In trying to find jobs searching fields from various tables i do something like this

```
@jobs = Job.find(:all, :joins => [:client,:contact,:location,:geofence], :conditions => ['geofences.address like ?',"%#{params[:term]}%"])
```

which produces the following error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'geofences_jobs_join.location_id'
```

from the following query

```
SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs`   INNER JOIN `clients` ON `clients`.id = `jobs`.client_id  INNER JOIN `contacts` ON `contacts`.id = `jobs`.contact_id  INNER JOIN `locations` ON `locations`.id = `jobs`.location_id  INNER JOIN `locations` geofences_jobs_join ON (`jobs`.`id` = `geofences_jobs_join`.`location_id`)  INNER JOIN `geofences` ON (`geofences`.`id` = `geofences_jobs_join`.`geofence_id`)  WHERE ...
```

Is there a way to fix this with either a different association in the jobs model or in the joins portion of my query?

I could get what I need using find_by_sql but i'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that in order to use a `has_one :through` association, your `Job` model should declare a `has_one :location` association, not the other way around, see [this example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-through-association).

That said, you can either try to redefine this association and move the location_id foreign key from the jobs table to job_id in locations, or try this query:

```
@jobs = Job.find(:all, :joins => [:client, :contact, { :location => :geofence }], :conditions => ['geofences.address like ?',"%#{params[:term]}%"])
```

In the latter case you'll have to remove the `has_one :through`.

Comment: I really can't change any db structure this is on a production app with millions of records. I was adding a new search feature to the jobs index. The query as you posted it produces a syntax error. But i think that may be on the right track.

Comment: I believe my issue is related to this bug https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/323-has_many-through-belongs_to_association-bug